# Non-trivial partitions of numbers using Combinatorica

Tags: syntax, combinatorics, partitions, combinatorica

I have made a code which gives back partitions of numbers in two Young diagrams (one Young diagram is trivial). For example, the partitions of 1 are

```
{{{0}, {1}}, {{1}, {0}}}
```

i.e. zero in first box and 1 in second box or 1 in the first box and zero for the second box. Of course the way it is written takes also into account antisymmetrization. So, if I choose the partitions of 2 then I will get back `{{{0}, {2}}, {{0}, {1, 1}}, {{1}, {1}}, {{2}, {0}}, {{1, 1}, {0}}}` where `{1, 1}, {0}` for example means I get the diagram pair with two boxes on top of each other and zero boxes while `{2}, {0}` gives the symmetric version, I get the pair with 2 boxes in horizontally and 0 boxes.

The **question** is how can I extend this for triples and quadruples of Young diagrams. I.e., for the partition of 1 to have

```
{{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}}
```

and so forth for the case I want it in 4 or more boxes. It would be great if the answer could also be slightly explained.

Comment: I've corrected and undeleted my answer undeleted

Answer (score 3):

Here's a generic answer:

```
YD[n_, d_] := 
 Cases[Tuples[
    Flatten[{Flatten[{Table[IntegerPartitions[i], {i, n, 1, -1}], 0}, 
         1], IntegerPartitions[n]}, 2] /. Table[{i} -> i, {i, n}] // 
     DeleteDuplicates, d], a_ /; TrueQ[Total[Flatten[a]] == n]] // 
  DeleteDuplicates
```

Here `n` is how high the numbers go, and `d` the amount of tuples.

The section:

```
Flatten[{Flatten[{Table[IntegerPartitions[i], {i, n, 1, -1}], 0}, 1], 
   IntegerPartitions[n]}, 2] /.Table[{i} -> i, {i, n}] // DeleteDuplicates
```

creates a list of all possible ways to partition `n` and every integer below `n`, so say if `n` is `3`, this gives us:

```
{3, {2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, 2, {1, 1}, 1, 0}
```

Note that you need to manually add a `0`.

The code then generates `Tuples[]` of `d` length from that list. Finally the `Cases[]` picks out the sublists that have a total value of `n`.

```
YD[1, 2]
```

> `{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}`

```
YD[2, 2]
```

> `{{2, 0}, {{1, 1}, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, {1, 1}}}`

```
YD[1, 3]
```

> `{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}`

Note that at a certain point, this gets memory intensive, and generating anything higher than `YD[5, 5]` requires a bit of patience.

```
YD[4, 4]
```

> `{{4, 0, 0, 0}, {{3, 1}, 0, 0, 0}, {{2, 2}, 0, 0, 0}, {{2, 1, 1}, 0, 0,
>      0}, {{1, 1, 1, 1}, 0, 0, 0}, {3, 1, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 1, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 
>     1}, {{2, 1}, 1, 0, 0}, {{2, 1}, 0, 1, 0}, {{2, 1}, 0, 0, 
>     1}, {{1, 1, 1}, 1, 0, 0}, {{1, 1, 1}, 0, 1, 0}, {{1, 1, 1}, 0, 0, 
>     1}, {2, 2, 0, 0}, {2, {1, 1}, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 0, 1}, {2,
>      0, 2, 0}, {2, 0, {1, 1}, 0}, {2, 0, 1, 1}, {2, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 
>     0, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, 2, 0, 0}, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, 0, 0}, {{1, 1}, 1, 
>     1, 0}, {{1, 1}, 1, 0, 1}, {{1, 1}, 0, 2, 0}, {{1, 1}, 0, {1, 1}, 
>     0}, {{1, 1}, 0, 1, 1}, {{1, 1}, 0, 0, 2}, {{1, 1}, 0, 
>     0, {1, 1}}, {1, 3, 0, 0}, {1, {2, 1}, 0, 0}, {1, {1, 1, 1}, 0, 
>     0}, {1, 2, 1, 0}, {1, 2, 0, 1}, {1, {1, 1}, 1, 0}, {1, {1, 1}, 0, 
>     1}, {1, 1, 2, 0}, {1, 1, {1, 1}, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 2}, {1,
>      1, 0, {1, 1}}, {1, 0, 3, 0}, {1, 0, {2, 1}, 0}, {1, 0, {1, 1, 1}, 
>     0}, {1, 0, 2, 1}, {1, 0, {1, 1}, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 
>     1, {1, 1}}, {1, 0, 0, 3}, {1, 0, 0, {2, 1}}, {1, 0, 
>     0, {1, 1, 1}}, {0, 4, 0, 0}, {0, {3, 1}, 0, 0}, {0, {2, 2}, 0, 
>     0}, {0, {2, 1, 1}, 0, 0}, {0, {1, 1, 1, 1}, 0, 0}, {0, 3, 1, 0}, {0,
>      3, 0, 1}, {0, {2, 1}, 1, 0}, {0, {2, 1}, 0, 1}, {0, {1, 1, 1}, 1, 
>     0}, {0, {1, 1, 1}, 0, 1}, {0, 2, 2, 0}, {0, 2, {1, 1}, 0}, {0, 2, 1,
>      1}, {0, 2, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 0, {1, 1}}, {0, {1, 1}, 2, 
>     0}, {0, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, 0}, {0, {1, 1}, 1, 1}, {0, {1, 1}, 0, 
>     2}, {0, {1, 1}, 0, {1, 1}}, {0, 1, 3, 0}, {0, 1, {2, 1}, 0}, {0, 
>     1, {1, 1, 1}, 0}, {0, 1, 2, 1}, {0, 1, {1, 1}, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 2}, {0,
>      1, 1, {1, 1}}, {0, 1, 0, 3}, {0, 1, 0, {2, 1}}, {0, 1, 
>     0, {1, 1, 1}}, {0, 0, 4, 0}, {0, 0, {3, 1}, 0}, {0, 0, {2, 2}, 
>     0}, {0, 0, {2, 1, 1}, 0}, {0, 0, {1, 1, 1, 1}, 0}, {0, 0, 3, 1}, {0,
>      0, {2, 1}, 1}, {0, 0, {1, 1, 1}, 1}, {0, 0, 2, 2}, {0, 0, 
>     2, {1, 1}}, {0, 0, {1, 1}, 2}, {0, 0, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {0, 0, 1, 
>     3}, {0, 0, 1, {2, 1}}, {0, 0, 1, {1, 1, 1}}, {0, 0, 0, 4}, {0, 0, 
>     0, {3, 1}}, {0, 0, 0, {2, 2}}, {0, 0, 0, {2, 1, 1}}, {0, 0, 
>     0, {1, 1, 1, 1}}}`

Comment: Feyre do you mind explaining the code a little bit?

Comment: @Marion While dissecting my own code to explain it, I've found a few ways to stream line the code a bit too. :)